# ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UserformService -> HttpClient]:

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

While trying to add a PrimeNG table I broke my build here: https://github.com/BillyCharter87/Tech-O-Dex-UI/tree/BrokeIt

I recall updating my `package.json` from TypeScript 2.3.4 to 2.4.0 and it broke due to (I think) the fact that I was using `Headers` and `Http` for my POST call. I tried setting it back to 2.3.4 to no avail. I have fixed what I could by adding in:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
```

but still running into the Error I have now for the `HttpClient`. I have tried importing `HttpClient` into the providers like so: `providers: [HttpClient]` for my app.module.ts.

The full error is as follows:

```
AppComponent.html:9 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HttpClient -> HttpHandler]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient -> HttpHandler]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpHandler!
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Make sure you have imported `HttpClientModule` instead of adding `HttpClient` direcly to the list of providers.

See https://angular.io/guide/http#setup for more info.

The `HttpClientModule` actually provides `HttpClient` for you. See https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientModule:

Code sample:

```
import { HttpClientModule, /* other http imports */ } from "@angular/common/http";

@NgModule({
    // ...other declarations, providers, entryComponents, etc.
    imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        // ...some other imports
    ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: get is not working if I am changing it to HttpClientModule   `public getServices(){   
    return this.http.get("http://report/abcd");   
  }`

Answer (score 33):

Import this in to app.module.ts

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
```

and add this one in imports

```
HttpClientModule
```

Answer (score 23):

In my case there was a need for:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'  // <- ADD THIS
})
export class FooService { ...
```

instead of just:

```js
@Injectable()
export class FooService { ...
```

Comment: Thanks this reolved my problem <3

Comment: Thank you good sir, you probably saved me a couple of hours. 1+

Answer (score 15):

Simply i have import in `appmodule.ts`

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
  imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     FormsModule,
     HttpClientModule  <<<this 
  ],
```

My problem resolved

Answer (score 3):

import the HttpClientModule in your app.module.ts

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

...
@NgModule({
...
  imports: [
    //other content,
    HttpClientModule
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

provide all custom services means written by you in component decorator section
Example : providers: [serviceName]

note:if you are using service for exchanging data between components. declare 
providers: [serviceName]
in module level

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible reasons
1. If you are using HttpClient in your service you need to import HttpClientModule in your module file and mention it in the imports array.

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

2. If you are using normal Http in your services you need to import HttpModule in your module file and mention it in the imports array.

   `import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http`'

By default, this is not available in the angular then you need to install @angular/http

If you wish you can use both HttpClientModule and HttpModule in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Add `HttpClientModule` in your `app.module.ts` and try, it will work so sure.
for example

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons for this error

1) In the array of import if you imported **HttpModule** twice

[image]

2) If you haven't import:

```
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

If you want then run:

**npm install @angular/http**