# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Http]: StaticInjectorError Http

Tags: angular

Got this error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Http]:
```

Here is code
Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MakeService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getMakes() {
    return this.http.get('api/makes')
      .pipe(map((response) => response.json()));
  }
}
```

App Module

```
import { MakeService } from './services/make.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './counter/counter.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './fetch-data/fetch-data.component';
import { VehicleFormComponent } from './vehicle-form/vehicle-form.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CounterComponent,
    FetchDataComponent,
    VehicleFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'vehicles/new', component: VehicleFormComponent },
      { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
      { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    MakeService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: import { MakeService } from '../services/make.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vehicle-form',
  templateUrl: './vehicle-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vehicle-form.component.css']
})
export class VehicleFormComponent implements OnInit {
  makes; 

  constructor(private makeService: MakeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.makeService.getMakes().subscribe(makes => {
      this.makes = makes;
      console.log("MAKES", this.makes);
    });
  }
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)\[UserformService -> HttpClient\]:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50013398/error-error-staticinjectorerrorappmoduleuserformservice-httpclient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have mixed the syntaxes that were used for making Http Calls before Angular 4.3 and after Angular 4.3

Angular 4.3 and prior used to use `Http` and for that, `HttpModule` was required to be added.

You're most probably using Angular with a version greater than 4.3 and RxJS version greater than 5.5

You should use `HttpClient`. You just need this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MakeService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getMakes() {
    return this.http.get('api/makes');
  }
}
```

Comment: And then i dont need to use .pipe(map((response) => response.json())); ?

Comment: Not at all. That's something that was needed in case of using `Http`.  HttpClient extract the `json` response from the response body. So you don't really need to call `json()` on the `response` anymore.